# s3 direct upload method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I'm using this gem to upload a file directly to S3

```
gem 's3_direct_upload'
```

https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: polymorphic_url([@academy, :dashboard,  @course, @lesson], {only_path: false}),callback_method: "PATCH", callback_param: "lesson[media]", id: "s3-uploader" do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>

  <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  <div id="file-{%=o.unique_id%}" class="upload">
    {%=o.name%}
    <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
  </div>
  </script>
```

File got successfully loaded

[image]

but, after the progress bar is completed, I see this error on console log:

```
PATCH http://localhost:3000/academies/1/dashboard/courses/1/lessons/3/edit 404 (Not Found)
```

**Controller**

```
class Dashboard::LessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :comment]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

    # PATCH/PUT /lessons/1
  # PATCH/PUT /lessons/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.update(lesson_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [:edit, @academy,  :dashboard, @course, @lesson], notice: 'Lesson was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @lesson }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: can you post your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Carrierwave. I had to disabled Carrierwave and everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

Looks like after updating, you redirect to `:edit` action, with `PATCH` request, if I'm right, your `:edit` action might only accept `GET` request.

I don't know in your `routes.rb`, how the `#edit` are set up, but you can try to modify the first line of your `_form.html.erb` file, and change `callback_method: "PATCH"` to `callback_method: "GET"`

Comment: No, I have to "PUT" to lessons/1 to save my new data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 404 so it's trying to hit the URL configured with the `callback_url` option, but not finding it.

Your callback URL is configured (evidently) as `/academies/1/dashboard/courses/1/lessons/3/edit` when you have no edit action in that controller.

You need to change your `callback_url` to point to (as the comment says) `.../lessons/3`, not `.../lessons/3/edit/`